# Why the latest version of Pandas fills rows with None but an earlier version fills with NaN after a concat and a column shift down operations?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following code produced different outputs with an earlier and the latest versions of Python and Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'b':[1,2,3,4,5],'a':[4.0,5.0,8.0,6.0,7.0],'c':[5,8,9,13,11]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b':[10,11],'a':[14,15],'d':['x','y']})
df = pd.concat([df,df2.iloc[1].to_frame().T], axis = 0, sort=False)
df['d'] = df['a'].shift(2)
print(df)
```

With Python 3.7.3 and Pandas 0.25.3, I got the following output:

```
    b     a     c    d
0   1   4.0   5.0  NaN
1   2   5.0   8.0  NaN
2   3   8.0   9.0  4.0
3   4   6.0  13.0  5.0
4   5   7.0  11.0  8.0
1  11  15.0   NaN  6.0
```

This is what I expected. However, with the latest Python 3.10.6 and Pandas 1.5.1, I got the following output:

```
    b     a     c    d
0   1   4.0   5.0  None
1   2   5.0   8.0  None
2   3   8.0   9.0  4.0
3   4   6.0  13.0  5.0
4   5   7.0  11.0  8.0
1  11  15.0   NaN  6.0
```

The two NaN in column 'd' became None. This caused problems for my later operations because None is an object while NaN is a float.
Why is the latest version produces None? This doesn't make sense to me. Or there is a deeper reason.

This difference in behave is also related to the pd.concat operation. Instead of

`df2.iloc[1].to_frame().T`

If I convert df2.iloc[1] into a dataframe via a dictionary like below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'b':[1,2,3,4,5],'a':[4.0,5.0,8.0,6.0,7.0],'c':[5,8,9,13,11]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b':[10,11],'a':[14,15],'d':['x','y']})
```

```
temp_dict = {}
for key,value in df2.iloc[1].items():
    temp_dict[key] = [value]
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(temp_dict)], axis = 0, sort=False)
```

```
df['d'] = df['a'].shift(2)
print(df)`
```

The None in column d will become NaN again with the latest versions. But I can't tell the different between the dataframes via a dictionary and via a to_frame().T operations.

Comment: I installed used python 3.10.6 and pandas 1.5.1 and was unable to replicate the error that you got. Perhaps consider uninstalling and reinstalling python and pandas and see if that clears your issue.

Comment: @tcglezen Sorry there was a typo in my post. I missed 'd':['x','y'] in my df2 line. Please see updated post. I added it back in and it reproduced. Without it, there was no difference. Could you try again?